# Java reading and then modifying binary tree and then saving changed tree to a text file

Tags: java, tree, binary

http://pastebin.com/72sGpe4V      -AnimalGuess class

http://pastebin.com/U4RSe5UE      -AnimalNode class

So the goal of the program is to have the computer guess what animal you are thinking of and if it doesn't, then the user adds in the animal they were thinking of and a question that would distinguish that animal from the previous animal.  Once the user chooses to not continue playing, the program exits.  Currently when the program exits, and then started up again, the program will not remember the questions the user put into the program during its previous run.  I need the program to read in a text file with or without binary tree data in it and then write out the new binary tree made by the user into a text file for later use.  I can't find the right place to put in where to write out the data to a text file. I thought it would be after line 13 in AnimalGuess.java but I keep getting errors.

Comment: `"...but I keep getting errors."` -- and what might those errors be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try iterating through contents of RootOfTree after the while loop ends and writing them to a file (right after line 14).